# Print an ordered dict info at specific lines in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, format

The issue I currently have is that I want to print the value I have stored for my dict using a format that will make it easy for the player in my game to read. That way it is easy to interpret what is going on.

I have searched around for the last while and I cannot find a solution to what I want. I find things that are similar but do not preform what I need. I think i am searching the wrong terms as I am still wet behind the ears at programming.

pprint seems like it could solve the issue but the documentation is hard to decipher for me. I have also tried using for loops and while loops to achieve the effect I want but I cannot iterate though my dict correctly to illicit the needed effect.

```
import collections

def generateBoard():
    board = {(x,y):'W' for y in range(1,11) for x in range(1,11)}
    oboard = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(board.items()))
    return oboard

def printBoard(board):
    for x, y in board.items():
        return y

board1 = generateBoard()
printBoard(board1)
```

Currently all it will do is print out the 'W' over and over again like so.

```
'W'
'W'
'W'
```

I would like it to print out like this.

```
'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W'
'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W'
'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W' 'W'
```

Again, I have tried several different looping methods but I cannot figure out how to join the data together. Also because I order the dict it will print out the key:data in the order I want just not the format I want.

```
def printBoard(board):
    while True:
        z = 0
        while x <11:
            p = 0
            z + 1
            while p < 11:
                if board[x,y] == 'W':
                    print y.join(x)
                p + 1
```

This is one of the ways I tried and it failed miserably. It will not let me use an iterator for the if statement which I kinda knew about but I cannot think of a way to get it to go through the x, y tuple to print out the data in a nice format.

EDIT:

I went with tr33hous suggestion of using a class and grc 's example also.
This code stores the values as I need them, and I can call the print function easily also.
I also have it only taking the first character of what ever string I have entered in that position. This way later I can just concatenate damaged + ship-name and it will still print the board in a very concise way.

```
class Board(object):
    '''Creates a board object with a print board method.'''

    def __init__(self, sides=11):
        self.sides = sides
        self.storedBoard = {(x,y):'W' for y in range(1,self.sides) for x in range(1,self.sides)}

    def print_board(self):
        printableBoard = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(self.storedBoard.items()))
        for y in range(1, self.sides):
            print ' '.join(str(printableBoard[x, y])[0] for x in range(1, self.sides))
```

I still do not know how I am going to completely implement ship damage or how it is tracked but I think this is a fairly good start. Right now though this lets me place the board and then I can run my ship placement script and it changes the 'W' value to the ship description.

Comment: I would advise you to create a `Board` class to do all this. That way, it can take care of stuff like this much easier and not be tied down to your specific board size

Comment: @grc and tr33hous thanks for the help. Not only did you solve my current issue but I used the information you provided to further my implementation of the Battleship game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
for y in range(1, 11):
    print ' '.join(board[x, y] for x in range(1, 11))
```

Here's a simpler method only using for loops:

```
for y in range(1, 11):
    for x in range(1, 11):
        # print the value followed by a single space
        print board[x, y],

    # print a new line
    print
```

Comment: Where did you learn this sorcery? Yes, that is exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot, this is a lot more complex than what i am used to. Is there any documentation or literature that has information on using for loops like this. Most of what I have found does not get as in depth as this. They just use basic for loops and while loops to achieve the effect needed.

Comment: @Owen E You can read here about [List Comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and about [Join](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm) method. Basically what @grc is doing is creating a list of elements and then `join` it to a string with fixed spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I'd advise using classes for something like this. I have reimplemented your code to reflect the change:

```
import collections 
class Board(object):
    def __init__(self, sides=11):
        self.sides = sides
        u_board = {(x,y):'W' for y in range(1,self.sides) for x in
                range(1,self.sides)}
        self.board = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(u_board.items()))

    def print_board(self):
        for y in range(1, self.sides):
            print ' '.join(self.board[x, y] for x in range(1, self.sides))



# Usage

b = Board()
b.print_board()
```

Output:

```
$ python board.py
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
W W W W W W W W W W
```

**EDIT** Modified print function to use  @grc 's method

Comment: I like how that is implemented. I moved the ordered script to my print function because I didn't like how it stored the information. This also keeps the integrity of the board and only modifies it for the print, the same thing I did in my current code. I do need the ability to modify the board on the fly though so i can change the positions of the board. Making the u_board into a class attribute solves this issue because I can just call it with b.u_board.

Comment: awesome, glad I helped. Could you mark it as the correct solution then.